# Neural Network Toolbox Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I've tried to create a neural network without using `nnstart` gui interface to train my network my own data (`x_train`, `y_train`).

```
clc
clear
close all

num = xlsread('ts1.xlsx','List1');
n = 100;
i = randperm(n);
x = num(i,:);
y = num(i,:);

x_train = x(1:fix(0.8*n),:);
y_train = x(1:fix(0.8*n),:);

x_test = x(fix(0.8*n)+1:end,:);
y_test = y(fix(0.8*n)+1:end,:);
net = feedforwardnet(15,'trainlm');
[net,tr] = train(net,x_train,y_train);
```

Neural network training results:

[image]

and so far it goes normal.

```
outputs = net(x_test);
```

But here I've some errors:

```
Error using network/sim (line 270)
Input data sizes do not match net.inputs{1}.size.

Error in network/subsref (line 15)
        otherwise, v = sim(vin,subs{:});

Error in Neural (line 19)
outputs = net(x_test);
```

Any suggestions to help me solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter; the same holds for code irrelevant to the issue (edited out). Also, please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); quoting: "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*"

Comment: Thanks for comment, i'll try my best as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tenth line, you wrote

```
y_train = x(1:fix(0.8*n),:);
```

Just replace x with y.